# Conditional to check URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I am using this code to try to verify a condition to change the style of the clicked link, but it did not work, because the logic of the code was supposed to work...

```
<ul>
   <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
     <li>  
       <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:link.target'>
         <span expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection'><data:link.name/></span>  
       <b:else/>      
         <a expr:href='data:link.target'><data:link.target/></a>
       </b:if>
     </li>
   </b:loop>
</ul>
```

Would there be any solution in JS or jQuery?

Comment: Does blogger allow you to have custom JS?

Comment: Yes, but only on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine Js code with Blogger conditional tag but if you can use page list widget instead of link list you can use `data:link.isCurrentPage` to check whether the url is the url of the current page

Page list code:

```
<ul>
   <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
     <li>  
       <b:if cond='data:link.isCurrentPage'>
         <span expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection'><data:link.title/></span>    
       <b:else/>        
         <a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a>
       </b:if>
     </li>
   </b:loop>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, your help worked for me.
A second solution for Linklist:

`<ul>
        <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
          <b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:link.target'>
            <li class='selected'><a expr:href='data:link.target'><data:link.name/></a></li>
          <b:else/>
            <li><a expr:href='data:link.target'><data:link.name/></a></li>
          </b:if>
        </b:loop>
      </ul>`